# Qt + Boost - Ошибки линковки при компиляции

Tags: c++, qt, boost

Сборка через VC++ 2013.
Куча ошибок LNK2019.
Все, что я пытаюсь сделать:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
```

Пример ошибки:

```
main.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __cdecl boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(enum boost::archive::archive_exception::_exception_code,char const *,char const *)" (??0archive_exception@archive@boost@@QEAA@W4_exception_code@012@PEBD1@Z) в функции "protected: void __cdecl boost::archive::basic_text_iprimitive<class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > >::load<int>(int &)" (??$load@H@?$basic_text_iprimitive@V?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@archive@boost@@IEAAXAEAH@Z)
```

В файле проекта указано:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/путь_к_главной_папке_boost
LIBS += -LC:/путь_к_главной_папке_boost/lib32-msvc-12.0
```

Т.е. заголовочные файлы он видит, а при сборке начинается какой-то бред

Comment: `-L` - это просто указание пути к библиотекам. А саму библиотеку кто подключать будет?

Comment: LIBS += -LC:/boost_1_63_0/lib32-msvc-12.0
LIBS += -lboost_serialization
Так? Теперь LNK1104: не удается открыть файл "lboost_serialization.obj". Нету этого файла нигде.

Comment: Если вы на MSVC, то путь указывается через `/LIBPATH:` а библиотека подключается просто указанием ее имени. Никакого `-l` не надо. У меня такое впечатление, что вы ключи `gcc` и линуксового `ln` пытаетесь скармливать майкрософтовскому `link.exe`. Он их не поймет.

Comment: У меня Qt, который использует MSVC. Я пытаюсь настроить это все через .pro файл проекта в Qt. Вы уверены, что в .pro файле Qt надо указывать параметры в виде, в котором они передаются консольному приложению? Приведите пример пожалуйста, я не понимаю

Comment: Я не уверен. Вполне может быть, что Qt умеет "транслировать" такие параметры. Однако обратите внимание на ваше сообщение об ошибке: "не удается открыть файл lboost_serialization.obj". Т.е. буква `l` оказалась частью имени файла, плюс прилепилось какое-то `.obj`.

Comment: Ну так объясните, как мне подключить. Во всех мануалах и других темах на stackoverflow говорится об этом способе. Но он не работает

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий кусок из моего проекта:

```
contains(QMAKE_TARGET.arch,x86_64): {
    LIBS += /LIBPATH:$$(BOOST_DIR)\\lib64-msvc-14.0
} else {
    LIBS += /LIBPATH:$$(BOOST_DIR)\\lib32-msvc-14.0
}
```